# Implementing interfaces using generics

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm new to generics and need some help.

I want to create an interface for all "transformer" classes to implement. To be a "transformer" the class must contain at least one variation of `T mapTo<T>(T t)`.

**HERE IS HOW I WANT TO USE TRANSFORMERS:**
Overload some methods...GREAT! Seems easy enough!

```
public class Transformer : ITransformer
{
    public Transformer(IPerson instance)
    {
    }

    public XmlDocument mapTo(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        // Transformation code would go here...
        // For Example:
        // element.InnerXml = instance.Name;

        return xmlDocument;
    }

    public UIPerson maptTo(UIPerson person)
    {
        // Transformation code would go here...
        // For Example:
        // person.Name = instance.Name;

        return person;
    }
}
```

**LET'S USE GENERICS TO DEFINE THE INTERFACE:**
Greate idea!

```
public interface ITransformer
{
     T MapTo<T>(T t); 
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
If I use generics in the interface my concrete class is LITERALLY forced to implement the following:

```
public T MapTo<T>(T t)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**THIS MAKES THE CLASS LOOK RATHER UGLY**

```
public class Transformer : ITransformer
{
    public Transformer(IPerson  instance)
    {
    }

    public XmlDocument MapTo(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        // Transformation code would go here...
        // For Example:
        // element.InnerXml = instance.Name;

        return xmlDocument;
    }

    public UIPerson MapTo(UIPerson person)
    {
        // Transformation code would go here...
        // For Example:
        // person.Name = instance.Name;

        return person;
    }

    public T MapTo<T>(T t)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add generic parameter to interface definition:

```
public interface ITransformer<T>
{
     T MapTo(T t); 
}
```

And implement all mappings you need:

```
public class Transformer : ITransformer<XmlDocument>, ITransformer<UIPerson>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public interface ITransformer<T>
{
    T MapTo(T t);
}
```

Then when you implement your interface, your class looks like:

```
public class Transformer : ITransformer<XmlDocument>
{
    public XmlDocument MapTo(XmlDocument t)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code from the original question you'd want to have `public class Transformer : ITransformer<XmlDocument>, ITransformer<UIPerson>`.  Which isn't a problem, but worth pointing out since the interface as implemented in the original question *doesn't* provide any kind of polymorphism.

Comment: So each transformer MUST be unique? Meaning, I can't simply overload?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `ITransformer` *interface* generic. So, you want this:

```
public interface ITransformer<T>
{
    public T MapTo(T t);
}
```

Then, when implementing the interface, classes can pass the interface the type parameter of the class that they wish to use:

```
public class Transformer : ITransformer<XmlDocument>
{
    public XmlDocument MapTo(XmlDocument t)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As lazyberezovsky said below, there's nothing stopping you from implementing the same interface multiple times:

```
public class Transformer : ITransformer<XmlDocument>, ITransformer<UIPerson>
```

Which must, of course provide implementations for `XmlDocument MapTo(XmlDocument t)` and `UIPerson MapTo(UIPerson t)`.

Comment: So each transformer MUST be unique? Meaning, I can't simply overload?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately so. You can overload the methods in the concrete class, there's nothing stopping you, but equally there won't be any interface forcing you to, unless you add the `ITransformer<T>` for each.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is have the following interface:

```
public interface ITransformer<TEntity> {
    public TEntity MapTo(TEntity entity);
}
```

Comment: So each transformer MUST be unique? Meaning, I can't simply overload?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO, no you'd just implement like has been shows in the answers above. `public class Transformer : ITransformer<XmlDocument>, ITransformer<UIPerson>`

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ITransformer<in TIn, out TOut>
{
    TOut Transform(TIn from);
}

public abstract class TransformerBase : ITransformer<IGatewayMessage, 
IMessageDto>
{
    public abstract IMessageDto Transform(IGatewayMessage source);
}

internal class GenericTransformer<TPayload> : TransformerBase where TPayload: class, IMessageDto, new() {
    TPayload payload;
    payload = ((aPayloadType) source.aPayload) as TPayload;
    payload.additionalProperty = source.additionalProperty;
    return payload;
}
```